# How to install eyeD3 on OSX?

Tags: install, macos

Can't seem to install eyeD3, any ideas?

```
matts-MacBook-Pro:~ matt$ sudo pip install eye3D

Downloading/unpacking eye3D
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement eye3D
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for eye3D
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/matt/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

For info:

```
matts-MacBook-Pro:~ matt$ python --version
Python 2.7.8

matts-MacBook-Pro:~ matt$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're writing 'eye3D' instead of 'eyeD3', that's probably it.

You want:

```
sudo pip install eyeD3
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things we miss...nice catch.

Comment: Oh yeah, schoolboy error. Can't believe it took 6 months for someone to spot this! Thanks.